# ServletContext initialize Timeout

Tags: web-deployment, servletcontextlistener

At deployment time we can do post-deployment *action* by overriding the method `contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce)` of the `ServletContextListener`.
Now we have the case that the *action* needs **more time**. So the deployment fails by a **timeout** (`java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException` exception). 
The time which is needed depends on the executed *action*. In the method we can compute the amout of time and would prefer to set the timeout there.
A possibility is to *trigger* the *action* and execute asynchronous. But this means extra effort.
The question is, is there a possibility to change the **timeout programatically** or is this a bad idea?

Example code:

```
  @WebListener
  public class PostDeployAction implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
      final ServletContext svtctx = sce.getServletContext();
      // do something that needs more time
    }
  }
```

On wildfly application server the deployment fails by error WFLYDC0074.

Answer (score 0):

For wildfly one solution is to increase the value of system property `jboss.as.management.blocking.timeout`

Comment: Thanks. This is correct. 
But this is a global setting for the container (wildfly).